# what's wrong with my exit condition

Tags: excel, perl

I have a script which parses an XLSX document and convert it in other format.

In the part where the XLSX file is red, i have an exit condition:

```
do 
   {
    ...
    ...
    ...
   }                      
until (uc(trim($worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0) -> value())) eq "");
```

unfortunately, when I am executing the script, I receive this error:

> Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at myfilename.pl line 94

Can anyone give me a hint or explain what what i am doing wrong, please?

by the way, I am a beginner in Perl programming.

Comment: uc() makes characters upper case, please consider removing it, since ("" eq uc("")) is true.

Comment: Please use while (condition) { block } structure, do not go into the specials in Perl, it is already special enough!

Comment: what module are you using to read from Excel file?

Comment: @MUY Belgium, thanks for your advice:
1. I removed the uc() function - indeed, it was useless
2. I changed the do{} until () into while () {}

now the script looks like

`
while (trim($worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0) -> value()) ne "")
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  print xmlFileHandler "<BU>".uc(trim($worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0) -> value()))."</BU>\n";
  $indexRow ++;
}`

unfortunately, the error message is the same ...any other idea?

Comment: @miguel Prz

I am using Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

Comment: @mikcutu I just wanna said, better use `while` than `until`.  The error message is detailed in my answer here under.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the expression

```
$worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0)
```

Is not defined.  So, no properties can be extracted.

My advice is to re-factor the code this way (but every body have his own advice) (take into considerations spaces in the second condition!):

```
while (1) # 1 is true
   {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    # suppose $indexrow has been calculated in the loop.
    if ( ! $worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0) ) {
        # do something (cell is not defined)
        # Cell is empty? (??????? 7 ?)
    } 
    elsif ( ! trim( $worksheet->get_cell($indexRow,0)->value() ) ) {
        last;  #escape this loop
    }
   }
```

Empty string is false, so `!` is equivalent to "the string is holding text".

Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean by "$worksheet -> get_cell($indexRow, 0)" is not defined...
normally, the cell($indexRow, 0) have value inside... and i just wnat to quit in case it don't have...

I was trying your example but it didn't work...

Comment: I do not know why, but in some cases the value returned by get_cell is not the usual object (you are used to, when the cell does exist) but one kind of NULL values, like 0, empty string, empty table, empty hash or possibly (do not use this) undef value.

Comment: i was trying to print $worksheet->get_cell(_value_in_the_range_) worksheet->get_cell(_empty_cell_in_the_range_) and also $worksheet->get_cell(_cell_out_of_the_range_) and the output was different:
cell in the range - cell[A:9]= Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH(0x3cb6cd0)
empty cell in the range - cell[A:9]= Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH(0x3cbc2b0)
celula din afara - cell[A:9]=

as it can be seen, the cell from the out of range is empty.

does anyone knows how to check if a cell is empty?!

Comment: For the moment, your are not testing if a cell is empty, your are testing if a cell contains only spaces.  But, aren't you happy with testing if value is empty?  But may be this is a other question?

Comment: you are right. that was the problem. i was changing the exit condition in the while with $worksheet->get_cell()... and it is working now
i just have to add the verification for the empty cell...

Comment: Sorry, I experiment some difficulties understanding the final code.  May you edit my post to tell people how to test empty cells?

Comment: I edited your post by adding the code and I also shall write an article about this.